# Populate dropdown with list

Tags: angular

I want to implement Angular example which gets list from rest API. I tried this:

SQL query:

```
    @Override
    public Iterable<Merchants> findAll() {
        String hql = "select e from " + Merchants.class.getName() + " e";
        TypedQuery<Merchants> query = entityManager.createQuery(hql, Merchants.class);
        List<Merchants> merchants = query.getResultList();
        return merchants;
    }
```

Rest controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/merchants")
public class MerchantController {

    @GetMapping("/list")
    public Iterable<Merchants> getMerchantsList() {
        return merchantRepository
                .findAll();
    }
}
```

**Service:**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MerchantService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }    
  getList() {
    return this.http.get("...../api/merchants/list");
  }
}
```

**Terminal Class:**

```
export class Terminal {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public enabled: string,
    public name: string,
    public merchant_id: number,
    public currency: string,
    public mode: string,
    public expires_at: Date 
  ) {}
}
```

**Merchant Class:**

```
export class Merchant {
  constructor(
    public id: string,
    public name: string,
    public state_raw: string,
    public users: string,
  ) {}
}
```

**Component:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-terminal',
  templateUrl: './terminal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./terminal.component.scss']
})
export class TerminalComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private terminalService: TerminalService,
              private merchantService: MerchantService,
              private router: Router,
              private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  } 

  merchants: Merchant[];

  ngOnInit() {   
    this.merchantService.getList()
      .subscribe(value => {
        if (value != null) {
          this.merchants = value;
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

**HTML form:**

```
<form class="grid-wrapper" #f="ngForm">
  <div *ngIf="edit" class="form-group id">
    <label for="id">Terminal Name</label>
    <input id="id" type="text" name="id" class="form-control" disabled [(ngModel)]="terminal.id">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group name">
    <label for="name">Terminal name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" name="name" class="form-control" required [(ngModel)]="terminal.name">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group type">
    <div class="input-group-prepend">
      <label for="type">Merchant</label>
    </div>
    <select class="custom-select" name="type" [(ngModel)]="terminal.merchant_id" id="merchant_id" required>
      <option selected></option>
      <option [value]="type" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-row">
    <button class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="f.invalid" (click)="submit()">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

When I load the web page the drop down menu is populated with 3 items. Do you know how I can show merchant name in drop down menu items but submit merchant `id` into the form as `merchant_id`?

I get this exception:

```
19:21:34,532 WARN  [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver] (default task-1) Resolved [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "undefined": not a valid Integer value; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.lang.Integer` from String "undefined": not a valid Integer value
 at [Source: (PushbackInputStream); line: 1, column: 56] (through reference chain: org.datalis.admin.backend.restapi.dto.TerminalDTO["merchant_id"])]
```

Comment: You're looping `<option [value]="type" *ngFor="let merchant of merchants">{{name}}</option>` the `merchants` but not even using the `merchant` object. Should of been `merchant.id` and `merchant.name`

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like that :

```
  <option *ngFor="let merchant of merchants" [value]="merchant.id" >{{ merchant.name }}</option>
```

The value attribute of option element is sent through the form.

Comment: either use property binding or use string interpolation `[value]="{{ merchant.id }}"` is not the right approach else someone will downvote this